# how to to make vuematerial cards as responsive

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to vuejs2 and trying to create a simple login page with the help of vue material.

```
<template>
  <div class="loginContainer">
    <form>
      <md-card class="md-layout md-small-size-33 md-medium-size-33">
        <md-card-header :data-background-color="dataBackgroundColor">
          <h4 class="title">Login</h4>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
          <div class="md-layout">
            <div class="md-layout-item">
              <md-field>
                <label>User Name</label>
                <md-input v-model="username" type="text"></md-input>
              </md-field>
            </div>
            <div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-33">
              <md-field>
                <label>Password</label>
                <md-input v-model="emailadress" type="password"></md-input>
              </md-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

in the above code I created a sample login page using vue-material cards.But how can I make these vue-material cards as responsive by using vue-material?

Comment: how can I change the size of the card at different screen size by using vue material